# "export 'default' (imported as 'Chart') was not found in 'chart.js'

Tags: chart.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css

Hi im getting this issue and can't quite figure why its saying it. im using vue3 with tailwind.

""export 'default' (imported as 'Chart') was not found in 'chart.js'"

Comment: Please add the code you're using - build a [mcve]. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem

Comment: Are you using https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-chartjs?

Answer (score 17):

Guess you are trying to import chart.js like this `import Chart from 'chart.js'`, since chart.js v3 chart.js is treeshakable so you will have to import and register all the components you want to use or import and register everything with the auto import like this: `import Chart from 'chart.js/auto'`

Docs: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/getting-started/integration.html#bundlers-webpack-rollup-etc

Comment: For me, `/auto` was the key.  I had been through nearly every tutorial I could find with no success [`vue 3.x`, `vuex 4.x`, `Chart.js 3.6.x`]. Was ready to beat myself to death with a hammer.  Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

For me, I just had to downgrade from chart.js@3.x to chart.js@2.9.4